# jQuery Masonry access internal method var

Tags: jquery

Any advice how to access an internal method var of jQuery Masony?
I'm looking to console.log the `containerSize` property inside the `layout` method:

line 177 > [query.masonry.js](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/jquery.masonry.js)

I need to retrieve the `containerSize` after masonry init:

```
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box'
});

console.log("here i need to retrieve the containerSize");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's impossible without rewriting the code or using a debugger to access values in variables from outside their scope at run time.

If you read the jQuery masonry source code, the containerSize gets pushed into an object data member called "styleQueue".  Unfortunately this is subsequently processed and emptied, which makes it pointless to try and access data from this member.

If you have a look in http://jsfiddle.net/5hgsm/1/ you will see that there is a lot of useful information in masonry's data.  Using a decent web-inspector such as Google Chrome's, you can explore the data object to view all the child elements.  You will more than likely find something in there that you can derive containerSize from.

However instead of trying to calculate containerSize from more abstract data, you could try just getting the width of the container directly and setting it after the resize animation completes.

This can be achieved by adding the "complete" callback to the animationOptions, as follows:

```
$('#container').masonry({      
    isAnimated: true,      
    itemSelector: '.box',      
    columnWidth: 102,      
    gutterWidth: 0,      
    isFitWidth: true,      
    isResizable: true,      
    animationOptions: {        
        duration: 400,        
        easing: 'swing',        
        queue: false, 
        // Add complete callback here:
        complete: function() {
            // Resize site header, do other stuff if you want
            $('#site-header').width($('#container').outerWidth());
        }  
    }    
});
```

This avoids the need to alter third party plugins, or calculate widths yourself from other data.

Comment: I updated the example to include fetching the width and height directly: http://jsfiddle.net/5hgsm/2/

Comment: As you can see here, I need to retrieve the containerSize with to pass it to #header e #footer elms in order to have the same with of .box container:  http://tinyurl.com/7fg7aa9 Now i succeed hardcoding at line 202 http://tinyurl.com/8xt8vdh

Comment: It's not really best practice to hard-code changes into software libraries.  As soon as you update to newer versions you lose all of your changes.  If you see the amended demonstration in my previous comment you will see a method of getting .box width and height.  But if you are after the width of the actual container of all of the boxes that is easy too, simply use $('#container').outerWidth() and you avoid all those potential problems caused by hacking changes into 3rd party code.

Comment: i know not to hack 3rd party code, thats why i'm searching a cleaner solution... I just tested what you say here: http://tinyurl.com/7fg7aa9 , but as you can see this is not good because the outherWidth is calculated before masonry animation.. try resize.

Comment: No problems, I wasn't accusing you of not knowing how to code, but you know, some people do not realise :)

I'll get back to you in a minute - I am pretty sure this can be done without a hack.

Comment: I'm running a new function and console.log succeed :) now i'm implement console.log(($('#container').data('masonry').cols)*(columnWidth));

Comment: as you said "there is a lot of data in masonry's data"!

Comment: Indeed there is!  When I discovered jQuery's "data" concept, a lot of things fell into place for me.  You can store state data in a clean way, which is awesome.  BTW I've updated my answer with an initialisation for masonry which gets rid of any complex logic - it uses the "complete" callback in the animationOptions settings.  It works quite well.